# Firebase Function Unable to Find userId and tweetId

Tags: firebase

I am using Firebase functions for Firestore database. I am trying to update a field based on the new tweet being added.

Here is my Firebase Function on production:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp() 

const db = admin.firestore() 

const functions = require("firebase-functions");

functions.logger.log("START OF FUNCTION");

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
                        .document('timelines/{userId}/tweets/{tweetId}')
                        .onCreate((change, context) => {
                            
                            const userId = context.params.userId 
                            const tweetId = context.params.tweetId 

                            functions.logger.log(context.params.userId);
                            functions.logger.log(context.params.tweetId);
                         
                         
                            db.doc(`/timelines/${userId}/tweets/${tweetId}`).update({likeCount: 200})
                        })
```

I am triggering it through an iPhone app. I am logged in to my account and I add a new Tweet. The Firebase function does get called but userId and tweetId are undefined. I am not sure why they are undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: It is indeed not normal, they should both have the expected value. Note that you should return the Promise returned by the `update()` method, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I will check on promise but I cannot even get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your client-side logic it's difficult to know if there are other issues. I would suggest adding some error handling to narrow down the cause. You could also try pulling it from the data response instead of context (assuming the schema matches).

Also note using 'snap' instead of 'change' as change is generally reserved for 'onWrite' and 'onUpdate' hooks.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('timelines/{userId}/tweets/{tweetId}')

  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    try {
      const { userId, tweetId } = snap.data();
      functions.logger.log(userId);
      functions.logger.log(tweetId);

      return await db.doc(`/timelines/${userId}/tweets/${tweetId}`).update({ likeCount: 200 });

    }
    catch (error) {
      functions.logger.log(error);
    }
  });
```